# C++ - pointer being freed was not allocated error

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x10ee008c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Or I get this when I try and print everything

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm doing some homework for an OOP class and I've been stuck for a good hour now. I'm getting this error once I've used keyboard input enough. I am not someone who gets frustrated at all, and here I am getting very frustrated with this. Here are the files:

This is the book class. I'm pretty sure this is very solid. But just for reference:

```
//--------------- BOOK.CPP ---------------
// The class definition for Book.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "book.h"

using namespace std;

Book::Book()
// 
{
  strcpy(title, " ");
  strcpy(author, " ");
  type = FICTION;
  price = 0;
}

void Book::Set(const char* t, const char* a, Genre g, double p)
{
  strcpy(title, t);
  strcpy(author, a);
  type = g;
  price = p;
}

const char* Book::GetTitle() const
{
  return title;
} 

const char* Book::GetAuthor() const
{
  return author;
}

double Book::GetPrice() const
{
  return price;
}

Genre Book::GetGenre() const
{
  return type;
}

void Book::Display() const
{
  int i;

  cout << GetTitle();
  for (i = strlen(title) + 1; i < 32; i++)
    cout << (' ');

  cout << GetAuthor();
  for (i = strlen(author) + 1; i < 22; i++)
    cout << (' ');

  switch (GetGenre())
  {
  case FICTION:
    cout << "Fiction   ";
    break;
  case MYSTERY: 
    cout << "Mystery   ";
    break;
  case SCIFI:
    cout << "SciFi     ";
    break;
  case COMPUTER:
    cout << "Computer  ";
    break;
  }

  cout << "$";
  if (GetPrice() < 1000)
    cout << " ";
  if (GetPrice() < 100)
    cout << " ";
  if (GetPrice() < 10)
    cout << " ";

  /* printf("%.2f", GetPrice());*/

  cout << '\n';
}
```

This is the store class that deals with the array and dynamic allocation. This was working well without input commands, but just using its functions it was working like a champ.

```
//--------------- STORE.CPP ---------------
// The class definition for Store.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>  // for strcmp
#include "store.h"

using namespace std;

Store::Store()
{
  maxSize = 5; 
  currentSize = 0; 
  bookList = new Book[maxSize];
}

Store::~Store()
// This destructor function for class Store
// deallocates the Store's list of Books
{
  delete [] bookList;
}

void Store::Insert(const char* t, const char* a, Genre g, double p)
// Insert a new entry into the direrctory.
{
  if (currentSize == maxSize)// If the directory is full, grow it.
    Grow();

  bookList[currentSize++].Set(t, a, g, p);
}

void Store::Sell(const char* t)
// Sell a book from the store.
{ 
  char name[31];
  strcpy(name, t);

  int thisEntry = FindBook(name);// Locate the name in the directory.

  if (thisEntry == -1)
    cout << *name << " not found in directory";
  else
    {
      cashRegister = cashRegister + bookList[thisEntry].GetPrice();
      // Shift each succeding element "down" one position in the
      // Entry array, thereby deleting the desired entry.
      for (int j = thisEntry + 1; j < currentSize; j++)
    bookList[j - 1] = bookList[j];

      currentSize--;// Decrement the current number of entries.
      cout << "Entry removed.\n";

      if (currentSize < maxSize - 5)// If the directory is too big, shrink it.
    Shrink();
    }
}

void Store::Find(const char* x) const
//  Display the Store's matches for a title or author.
{
  // Prompt the user for a name to be looked up

  char name[31];
  strcpy(name, x);

  int thisBook = FindBook(name);
  if (thisBook != -1)
    bookList[thisBook].Display();

  int thisAuthor = FindAuthor(name, true);

  if ((thisBook == -1) && (thisAuthor == -1))
    cout << name << " not found in current directory\n";
}

void Store::DisplayGenre(const Genre g) const
{
  double genrePrice = 0;
  int genreCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)// Look at each entry.
  {  
    if (bookList[i].GetGenre() ==  g)
    {
      bookList[i].Display();
      genrePrice = genrePrice + bookList[i].GetPrice();
      genreCount++;
    }
  }
  cout << "Number of books in this genre: " << genreCount
       << "                    " << "Total:    $";
  if (genrePrice < 1000)
    cout << " ";
  if (genrePrice < 100)
    cout << " ";
  if (genrePrice < 10)
    cout << " ";

  printf("%.2f", genrePrice);
}

void Store::DisplayStore() const
{
  if (currentSize >= 1)
  {
    cout << "**Title**\t\t"
     << "**Author**\t"
     << "**Genre**\t"
     << "**Price**\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
      bookList[i].Display();
  }
  else
    cout << "No books currently in inventory\n\n";

  cout << "Total Books = " << currentSize 
       << "\nMoney in the register = $";
  if (cashRegister < 1000)
    cout << " ";
  if (cashRegister < 100)
    cout << " ";
  if (cashRegister < 10)
    cout << " ";

  printf("%.2f", cashRegister);

  cout << '\n';
}

void Store::Sort(char type)
{
  Book temp;

  for(int i = 0; i <= currentSize; i++)
  {
    for (int j = i+1; j < currentSize; j++)
    {
      if (type == 'A')
      {
    if (strcmp(bookList[i].GetTitle(), bookList[j].GetTitle()) > 0)
    {
      temp = bookList[i];
      bookList[i] = bookList[j];
      bookList[j] = temp;
    }
      }
      if (type == 'T')
      {
    if (strcmp(bookList[i].GetAuthor(), bookList[j].GetAuthor()) > 0)
    {
      temp = bookList[i];
      bookList[i] = bookList[j];
      bookList[j] = temp;
    }
      }
    }
  }
}

void Store::SetCashRegister(double x)
// Set value of cash register
{
  cashRegister = x;
}

void Store::Grow()
// Double the size of the Store's bookList
// by creating a new, larger array of books
// and changing the store's pointer to refer to
// this new array.
{
  maxSize = currentSize + 5;// Determine a new size.

  cout << "** Array being resized to " << maxSize 
       << " allocated slots" << '\n';

  Book* newList = new Book[maxSize];// Allocate a new array.

  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)// Copy each entry into
    newList[i] = bookList[i];// the new array.

  delete [] bookList;// Remove the old array
  bookList = newList;// Point old name to new array.
}

void Store::Shrink()
// Divide the size of the Store's bookList in
// half by creating a new, smaller array of books
// and changing the store's pointer to refer to
// this new array.
{
  maxSize = maxSize - 5;// Determine a new size.

  cout << "** Array being resized to " << maxSize 
       << " allocated slots" << '\n';

  Book* newList = new Book[maxSize];// Allocate a new array.

  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)// Copy each entry into
    newList[i] = bookList[i];// the new array.

  delete [] bookList;// Remove the old array
  bookList = newList;// Point old name to new array.
}

int Store::FindBook(char* name) const
// Locate a name in the directory.  Returns the
// position of the entry list as an integer if found.
// and returns -1 if the entry is not found in the directory.
{
  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)// Look at each entry.
    if (strcmp(bookList[i].GetTitle(), name) == 0)
      return i;// If found, return position and exit.

  return -1;// Return -1 if never found.
}

int Store::FindAuthor(char* name, const bool print) const
// Locate a name in the directory.  Returns the
// position of the entry list as an integer if found.
// and returns -1 if the entry is not found in the directory.
{
  int returnValue;

  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)// Look at each entry.
    if (strcmp(bookList[i].GetAuthor(), name) == 0)
    {
      if (print == true)
    bookList[i].Display();
      returnValue = i;// If found, return position and exit.
    }
    else
      returnValue = -1;// Return -1 if never found.

  return returnValue;
}
```

Now this is the guy who needs some work. There may be some stuff blank so ignore that. This one controls all the input, which is the problem I believe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "store.h"

using namespace std;

void ShowMenu()
// Display the main program menu.
{
  cout << "\n\t\t*** BOOKSTORE MENU ***";
  cout << "\n\tA \tAdd a Book to Inventory";
  cout << "\n\tF \tFind a book from Inventory";
  cout << "\n\tS \tSell a book";
  cout << "\n\tD \tDisplay the inventory list";
  cout << "\n\tG \tGenre summary";
  cout << "\n\tO \tSort inventory list";
  cout << "\n\tM \tShow this Menu";
  cout << "\n\tX \teXit Program";
}

char GetAChar(const char* promptString)
// Prompt the user and get a single character,
// discarding the Return character.
// Used in GetCommand.
{
  char response;// the char to be returned

  cout << promptString;// Prompt the user
  cin >> response;// Get a char,
  response = toupper(response);// and convert it to uppercase
  cin.get();// Discard newline char from input.
  return response;
}

char Legal(char c)
// Determine if a particular character, c, corresponds
// to a legal menu command.  Returns 1 if legal, 0 if not.
// Used in GetCommand.
{
  return((c == 'A') || (c == 'F') || (c == 'S') || 
     (c == 'D') || (c == 'G') || (c == 'O') || 
     (c == 'M') || (c == 'X'));
}

char GetCommand()
// Prompts the user for a menu command until a legal 
// command character is entered.  Return the command character.
// Calls GetAChar, Legal, ShowMenu.
{
  char cmd = GetAChar("\n\n>");// Get a command character.

  while (!Legal(cmd))// As long as it's not a legal command,
    {// display menu and try again.
      cout << "\nIllegal command, please try again . . .";
      ShowMenu();
      cmd = GetAChar("\n\n>");
    }
  return cmd;
}

void Add(Store s)
{
  char aTitle[31];
  char aAuthor[21];
  Genre aGenre = FICTION;
  double aPrice = 10.00;

  cout << "Enter title: ";
  cin.getline(aTitle, 30);

  cout << "Enter author: ";
  cin.getline(aAuthor, 20);
  /*
  cout << aTitle << "  " << aAuthor << "\n";
  cout << aGenre << "  " << aPrice << '\n';
  */
  s.Insert(aTitle, aAuthor, aGenre, aPrice);

}

void Find()
{
}

void Sell()
{
}

void ViewGenre(Store s)
{
  char c;
  Genre result;

  do
    c = GetAChar("Enter Genre - (F)iction, (M)ystery, (S)ci-Fi, or (C)omputer: ");
  while ((c != 'F') && (c != 'M') && (c != 'S') && (c != 'C'));

  switch (result)
    {
    case 'F': s.DisplayGenre(FICTION);    break;
    case 'M': s.DisplayGenre(MYSTERY);    break;
    case 'S': s.DisplayGenre(SCIFI);      break;
    case 'C': s.DisplayGenre(COMPUTER);   break;
    }

}

void Sort(Store s)
{
  char c;
  Genre result;

  do
    c = GetAChar("Enter Genre - (F)iction, (M)ystery, (S)ci-Fi, or (C)omputer: ");
  while ((c != 'A') && (c != 'T'));

  s.Sort(c);
}

void Intro(Store s)
{
  double amount;

  cout << "*** Welcome to Bookstore Inventory Manager ***\n"
       << "Please input the starting money in the cash register: ";
  /*  cin >> amount;

      s.SetCashRegister(amount);*/
}

int main()
{
  Store mainStore;// Create and initialize a Store.

  Intro(mainStore);//Display intro & set Cash Regsiter

  ShowMenu();// Display the menu.

  /*mainStore.Insert("A Clockwork Orange", "Anthony Burgess", SCIFI, 30.25);
    mainStore.Insert("X-Factor", "Anthony Burgess", SCIFI, 30.25);*/

  char command;// menu command entered by user
   do
     {
       command = GetCommand();// Retrieve a command.
       switch (command)
     {
     case 'A': Add(mainStore);             break;
     case 'F': Find();                     break;
     case 'S': Sell();                     break;
     case 'D': mainStore.DisplayStore();   break;
     case 'G': ViewGenre(mainStore);       break;
     case 'O': Sort(mainStore);            break;
     case 'M': ShowMenu();                 break;
     case 'X':                             break;
     }
     } while ((command != 'X'));

   return 0;
}
```

Please, any and all help you can offer is amazing.
Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce to a smaller program that still illustrates the problem. Also provide a stack trace when the error is raised.

Comment: You pass `Store` by value to `Add`, `ViewGenre`, etc. After you fix this bug, that will be the cause of the next bug you discover.

Comment: Do not mix cin.get with >>.

To discard new lines, etc. use a if.

Good luck!

Comment: @Rob that may very well be one of the two posted!

Comment: Please provide headers as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome to the exciting world of C++!

Short answer: you're passing Store as a value. All your menu functions should take a Store& or Store* instead.

When you're passing Store as a value then an implicit copy is done (so the mainStore variable is never actually modified). When you return from the function the Store::~Store is called to clean up the copied data. This frees mainStore.bookList without changing the actual pointer value.

Further menu manipulation will corrupt memory and do many double frees.

HINT: If you're on linux you can run your program under valgrind and it will point out most simple memory errors.

Comment: Yes, Rob said this as a comment and that was the problem. Thank you so much as well.

Answer (score 7):

Your `Store` contains dynamically-allocated data, but does not have an assignment operator. You have violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I deleted the answer and put it as a comment.

Comment: I will not have to use an assignment operator for this, but I know what you mean.

Comment: If you want to obey the rule of three for the Store class it would  be best to declare a dummy private copy constructor and assignment operator. Or just inherit from boost::noncopyable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the Store class being instantiated anywhere by a call to `new Store()` which means the booklist array has not been created but when the program exits and calls the destructor, it tries to remove the array that was never allocated and hence that's why i think you are getting this error. Either, modify the destructor to have a null check or instantiate the class by a call to the constructor. Your code shouldn't still be working anywhere you are trying to use a `Store` object.

Hope this helps

Comment: Fixed this! I don't think this was the source of the problem, but thank you!

Comment: but it was one of the problems, wasn't it ? :) I just hope the if I gave a "medicine" it should fix "headache" if not "stomach-ache".. ;)